# HERE maps SDK iOS - current road element is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

We've included premium HERE Maps iOS SDK into our app. In particular, we were looking into `NMANavigationManager.shared().startTracking(with: .car)` functionality (used when user starts driving).

It all worked well for a while (2 days or so), but now it all of a sudden stopped working. I'm using the same code as before - nothing changed. I'm also taking the same route. I'm observing the `Notification.Name.NMAPositioningManagerDidUpdatePosition`
 notification when location changes.

In there I look for `NMAPositioningManager.shared().currentRoadElement()` which is always set to nil (despite location being correct). `didUpdateSpeedingStatus` is never called too, despite `NMANavigationManager.shared().isSpeedWarningEnabled` being set to true.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: did you find a solution for that?

Comment: @Shial yes, I forgot to download the maps after the fresh install (you need maps locally)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments above, it is a pre-requsite to have the offline map data using the HERE Mobile Premium SDK NMAMapLoader interface to download the data onto the device if the SDK is in Tracking mode.